# Limit the number of rows displayed in Items control

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

Is there a way to limit the number of rows that get displayed in items control. ?

I have a observable collection of strings which are bound to Items control. I want to limit the number of rows to display to only one. The collection can have more than one.

Thanks,

Comment: How do you determine which item of the collection to show? How can the user change the selected item? Please change your question to add more info, don't answer you own question in order to do so.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `IValueConverter` for this:

```
public class ItemsLimiter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int count;
        if (Int32.TryParse((string)parameter, out count))
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<object>)value).Take(count);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In XAML you can use it like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Data, Converter={StaticResource ItemsLimiter}, ConverterParameter=12}">
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your `ItemsSource` is set to `MyObservableCollection`.

Well, what if you change your `ItemsSource` so that it is pointing a `MyOneItemCollection` instead?

Then, just use LINQ to do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;
MyOneItemCollection = MyObservableCollection.First();
```

or

```
using System.Linq;
MyOneItemCollection = MyObservableCollection.Single(item => item.Id = MyId);
```

Comment: This enumerates the collection into a different list, which will lose all connections to OnCollectionChanged. I.e. when you update your observable collection your UI will not update unless you do a complete refresh

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever need one item to display you can show the first item using a ContentControl instead with the same available templating options:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{erm:Items FieldName}" Content="{Binding [0]}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my PaginatedObservableCollection here http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2008/12/paginated-observablecollection.html

This is a subclassed observableCollection which lets you bind to N items and make the UI display 'n' items when you set ItemsPerPage. In your case if you put 1 and can bind the next and previous also to some buttons as in my sample.

Hope this give you some idea.

Comment: I dont have any control over the observable collection. I cannot change it to use the paginatedObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom `CollectionView` that only provides `n` elements. I did something similar in my autocomplete textbox control implementation, check it out here:

[A Reusable WPF Autocomplete TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete_textbox.aspx)

Scroll down to the header titled `Limiting the Completions List` see what I did there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a `CollectionView` that produces only a single item.  This is quite simple:  Just subclass `CollectionView` and override `OnCollectionChanged` to set a filter to filter out everything except the first item in the underlying collection:

```
protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
  base.OnCollectionChanged(args);
  var first = SourceCollection.FirstOrDefault();
  Filter = (obj) => obj == first;
}
```

Now you need to insert this `CollectionView` into your `ItemsSource`.  If `erm:Items`'s `ProvideValue` produces the actual collection or a Binding with no Converter, you can just create your own MarkupExtension which either wraps it in your custom view or adds a Converter to do the wrapping.  On the other hand, if erm:Items produces a Binding that already has a Converter or you can't rely on knowing what it produces, you should probably use a more general solution - I would suggest attached properties.

To use attached properties, your ItemsControl will be bound like this:

```
<ItemsControl
  my:SinglerCollectionViewCreator.ItemsSource="{erm:Items FieldName}"
  ... />
```

and the code in the SinglerCollectionViewCreator class would be:

```
public class SinglerCollectionViewCreator : DependencyObject
{
  public object GetItemsSource(...  // use "propa" snippet to fill this in
  public void SetItemsSource(....
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = ...
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e)
    {
      obj.SetValue(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty,
        new SinglerCollectionView(e.NewValue));
    }
  }
}
```

The way this work is, whenever your new `SinglerCollectionViewCreator.ItemsSource` property is set on any object, the value is wrapped inside your `SinglerCollectionView` class and the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` is set on the same object.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way to do this entirely in XAML, without writing code?

```
<ItemsControl Height="100"  ItemsSource="{erm:Items FieldName}" Grid.Row="1" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
</ItemsControl>
```

I have the items source bound like above. The Items markup extension returns observable collection of strings and I have no control over the observable collection.